Expectation of a non-negative discrete random variable
For a non-negative discrete random variable $Z$ and some constant $z$, prove that
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z] \leq z + \sum_{t\geq 0} \Pr [Z\geq 2^t\cdot z]\cdot 2^{t+1}z.
$$
I have tried to prove by using the fact that for a non-negative integer-valued random variable $Z$, $\mathbb{E}[Z]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \Pr[Z\geq k]$. However, the random varible $Z$ in the inequality to be proved is only a discrete random variable, not necessarily integer-valued. I have also tried to figure out the intution of the expression (i.e., partition of dyadic intervals) but have no idea. Any hints are welcome, thanks!

Welcome to Math StackExchange. For best results (i) Clearly state your problem. (ii) Show your own effort at attempting the problem. (If you have made no effort yet, it is too early to post the problem.)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@paw88789: Thank you for your kind reminder. I have edited the post and added my own effort at attempting the problem.

Let $I_{-1} = [0,z)$ and $I_t = [2^t z, 2^{t+1} z)$ for $t\ge 0$. Then
$$
   \mathbb E[Z] = \sum_{t=-1}^\infty \mathbb E[Z \mid Z \in I_t] \Pr[Z\in I_t] \le \sum_{t=-1}^\infty 2^{t+1}z \Pr[Z\in I_t],
$$
because when $Z \in I_t$, $Z \le 2^{t+1}z$.
Also, we can write $\Pr[Z \ge 2^t z]$ as $\sum_{s \ge t} \Pr[Z \in I_s]$, and write $z$ as $z \cdot \sum_{s \ge -1} \Pr[Z \in I_s]$ to make it part of the bigger sum, which means that the RHS of the sum we're looking at is $$\sum_{t \ge -1} 2^{t+1}z \sum_{s=t}^\infty \Pr[Z \in I_s].$$ Interchange the order of summation to get $$\sum_{s=-1}^\infty \left(\sum_{t=-1}^s 2^{t+1}z\right)\Pr[Z \in I_s] = \sum_{s=-1}^\infty (2^{s+2}-1) \Pr[Z \in I_s].$$ Comparing this to our upper bound on $\mathbb E[Z]$, we see that $2^{t+2}-1 \ge 2^{t+1}$ for all $t \ge -1$, so the inequality we want holds.
The inequality $2^{t+2}-1 \ge 2^{t+1}$ gives away a lot for large $t$, so the similar bound $$\mathbb E[Z] \le z + \sum_{t \ge 0} \Pr[Z \ge 2^t \cdot z] \cdot 2^t z$$ is sharper. If we do the same trick of interchanging the order of summation here, then the coefficient of $\Pr[Z \in I_s]$ ends up being $z + z + 2z + \dots + 2^s z$, which is exactly the $2^{s+1}z$ we want.
